# Trying to make a div background image 100% height of window and div centered

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a page that fills the screen on an iPad and has 2 black edges on an iPhone as the aspect ratio is different.

The background image needs to stay fixed shape, not stretched.

I've managed to make the div background, the right size and shape, but I can't centre it. Can anyone help?
http://www.simonpetermedia.com/Aboutpage/about.html

```
html{
height:100%;
}
body {
    font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;

    background: #000000;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #000000;
}
.oneColElsCtr #container {
position:fixed !important;

top:0;
right:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;

    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("aboutbg.jpg");
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    text-align: left; 
    min-height: 100%;
}
.oneColElsCtr #mainContent {
    padding: 0px; 
}
-->
</style></head>

<body class="oneColElsCtr">

<div id="container">
  <div id="mainContent">
    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
    <!-- end #mainContent --></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: There are two ways of horizontally centering somethig: `display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 100px;` _or_ `display: inline-block;` and `text-align: center;` on the parent. For the first option you _must_ specify a `width`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background-size:cover;
```

Edited to

```
background-size:contain; background-position:center;backround-color:#E2AA7B;
```

Comment: It does not stretch it but it does cut from the bottom if in landscape mode.

Comment: this will be work out?background-size:contain;
background-position:center;backround-color:#E2AA7B;

Comment: That kind of works - it centres the background, but I need to div to be centered and display the whole image, so content will be displayed on to of the image.

Comment: This along with making mainContent height 100% and width 75% works - thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this to `#container` css

`background-position: center center;`

Comment: This centres the background, but I need to div to be centered and display the whole image

Answer (score 0):

I have opened your page on Google Chrome and have opened the element inspector. At your "container" div, put a "background-position: center;" to make it stick horizontally to center.